# SharePoint survey list: anonymous access can participate several times

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, anonymous-authentication, survey-list

I'm having a SharePoint survey list created in an internet site, with anonymous access enabled to the entire web, the anonymous access can participate in the survey response, but the list configuration that prevents multiple responses does not actually work with anonymous users, it does only with authenticated users.

[image]

So I need to find a solution to prevent anonymous users to respond more than once, is there any way I can achieve this ?  whether writing a custom event receiver or finding an OOTB solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to remove anonymous access to the list, but it will prevent any response from anonymous users.

Go to list permissions, stop inheriting permissions and remove anonymous access.

Comment: I can't remove anonymous access to the list, anonymous users must participate and respond to the surveys.

Comment: @MohammadAkilan Your problem is that you only want one (1) response from anonymous users. Anonymous users are by definition anonymous, and can't be tracked or limited to one. It's either none or infinite.